# Comparing id from user to a table asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

As I am new to coding I have to get an id from user and compare it to a table from students that contains a foreign key of sectionid. I would really appreciate if you help me what to do next I have searched but I'm not understanding anything.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CheckSectionIDagainststudentID(string sectionID)
{
    int x = Int32.Parse(sectionID);

    ConnectionManager connManager = new ConnectionManager();
    SqlConnection conn = connManager.GetConnection();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * From Student Where sectionid = " + x;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you MIGHT be close (not knowing all your tables), I would finish what you have using a SqlDataAdapter.  That does a bunch of the work for you when loading into a table.

replace your "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()" line with something like.

```
var sda - new SqlDataAdapter();
sda.Command = cmd;
var tbl = new DataTable();
sda.Fill( tbl );
```

This should pull down all records and put into a datatable object for you.  Then you can go through each record and do whatever you need.

Also, fix your parameters.  if expecting a number, do so.  But from a web post, everything comes in as string and you need to parse as you have done.  use int.TryParse() command (read up on that), to prevent crash if some bad text comes in unexpectedly.

Finally fix your query now and all future to prevent sql-injection.  use place-holders and then your parameter, such as

```
cmd.CommandText = "Select * From Student Where sectionid = @parmSectionID";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "parmSectionID", x );
```

Dont add the "@" to the string representation in the parameters line.

Definitely read-up on more SQL commands throughout S/O and also SQL-Injection especially this early on in your development.  Dont start with bad techniques that will bite you in the long run.